# Display google charts negative value left from positive instead of right

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I'm using `chartkick` gem for building Google Charts in my rails app.
But I have a problem with displaying negative values in line chart. Negative value goes after the positive instead of before.
[image]

I have tried to google how to fix it, but didn't find any solution.

code sample:

```
<%= line_chart([{name: 'name_1', data: @data_for_chart_1},
                {name: 'name_2', data: @data_for_chart_2}], discrete: true,
                xtitle: "Cut Expenses By ($)", ytitle: "Max. Home Price ($)",
                colors: ["#2E3192", "red"], library: {title: "Cutting Expenses Makes Higher Priced Homes Affordable", curveType: "none", pointSize: 0, legend: { position: "bottom" }}, id: "chart" ) %>
```

`@data_for_chart_1` and `@data_for_chart_2` are integer keys and values.

Comment: @WhiteHat description updated

Comment: you need an Continuous axis, instead of Discrete -- see [discrete vs continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous) -- try `discrete: false` --> but values must be numbers, not strings

Comment: @WhiteHat yes i tried discrete false. Maybe `set the data column type to number` means to put `type: number`  somewhere else? Or maybe it is not working in Rails?

Comment: not sure about Rails -- can you share a sample of `@data_for_chart_1` or `@data_for_chart_2`?

Comment: @WhiteHat `{0=>173929, 70=>185474, 140=>197018, 210=>208563, 280=>220108, 350=>231653, 420=>243197, 490=>254742, 560=>266287, 630=>270900}`